# AngularJS: how to copy selected table rows to clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created a table with an option to select rows by checkboxes which works fine.

Now I am looking for something - idea, example, similar case - to help me copy those selected rows to clipboard to paste them into Excel file one under another.

I can filter through all items list by `checked` property in a controller or through AngularJS's `filter` functionality.

**My table:**

```
<button ng-click="copySelected()" type="button">Copy selected to clipboard</button>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-change="toggleAll()"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk-{{item.id}}" ng-model="options[$index]" ng-value="item.id" 
                ng-change="toggleItem($index)"></td>
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.issueDate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.subject}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**AngularJS controller:**

```
$scope.selectAll = false;
$scope.options = [];


$scope.toggleItem = function(index) {
   $scope.items[index].checked = !$scope.items[index].checked;
   if (!$scope.items[index].checked) {
      $scope.selectAll = false;
   }
};
  
$scope.toggleAll = function() {
   var checked = $scope.selectAll;
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
     $scope.options[i] = checked;
     $scope.items[i].checked = checked;
   }
};

// this is where I don't know how to progress from
$scope.copySelected = function() {
    
    if ($scope.selectAll) {
        
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].checked) {
                

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to transform the selected items array in a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format. Then you can use the browsers [clipboard api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) to write the csv payload to the clipboard.

When I do this in Libreoffice - the app prompts me to import the text format when copy and pasting into a workbook. In Excel this might need some tweaking or it even requires formatting the data by the user.

- You can also just generate an Excel file using [SheetJs](https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs) - but maybe to bloated for your use case.
- You could send the generated CSV directly to the browser.

The clipboard api is not available in IE.

Comment: Yes, I started with generating an Excel file but it seemed too much. With transforming selected items array in a CSV format, can it be done without saving anything on a local drive or on a server?

Comment: @MrP CSV is just a string/text of separated values. You can simply assign it to a variable and write the payload to the clipboard. There is no need for an intermediate "file".